# How can I enlarge the "label" and "dropdown" content?

Tags: asp.net-core, frontend, devexpress

How can I enlarge the "label" and "dropdown" content?

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

problem solved thank you :
I used <div class="col-sm-12" instead of <div class="col-sm-6" and the problem was solved.

```
<div class ="row clearfix">..
 <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom : 0px !important;padding..
 <div class="dx-fieldsex">...
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Instead,  include it as text. Also please explain *what* the code does and *how* it solves the problem. Keep in mind the whole point of you posting an answer is so that others in the future may find it helpful. It's difficult to do that if they don't know what you did and what it does.